# How to type a component prop in a way that it works with both singular usage and within loops without breaking intellisense?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, intellisense, prop

### The Setup

I have a heading component whose types look like this.

```js
// Heading/index.d.ts
import { HTMLAttributes } from 'react';

export const HeadingType: {
  product: 'product';
  marketing: 'marketing';
};
export const HeadingLevel: {
  h1: 'h1';
  h2: 'h2';
  h3: 'h3';
  h4: 'h4';
  h5: 'h5';
  h6: 'h6';
};

export interface HeadingProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> {
  as: keyof typeof HeadingLevel;
  type?: keyof typeof HeadingType;
}
export const Heading: React.FC<HeadingProps>;
```

Here's what the `as` type gets inferred as, which is what I want because that makes the intellisense work really well at the consumer side.

**Inference**
[image: The as type inference]

**Component Usage**
[image: The usage site of Heading]

The problem is that this doesn't work if I have to generate the element in a loop using let's say, `map` because the actual data I wanna use may be string.

The error I am given on hovering over `as` is

```
Type '`h${number}`' is not assignable to type '"h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6"'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(17, 3): The expected type comes from property 'as' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HeadingProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

[image: Looping Scenario]

### The Question

How do I type this so both the cases work?

### Notes

If you are wondering why I have an `export const HeadingLevel` in the `index.d.ts` file and simply the union type is because the actual component is written in JS, which exports two variables with the same name that look like this.

[image: The actual HeadingLevel object in .js]

Answer (score 2):

You need to build some kind of Loose Completion type helper like this

```
export const HeadingType: {
  product: 'product';
  marketing: 'marketing';
};
export const HeadingLevel: {
  h1: 'h1';
  h2: 'h2';
  h3: 'h3';
  h4: 'h4';
  h5: 'h5';
  h6: 'h6';
};

type HeadingLevelUnion = keyof typeof HeadingLevel;
type HeadingTypeUnion = keyof typeof HeadingType;

export interface HeadingProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> {
  as: HeadingLevelUnion | Omit<string, HeadingLevelUnion>;
  type?: HeadingTypeUnion | Omit<string, HeadingTypeUnion>;
}
```

Reference : [MattPocock Loose Autocomplete](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_m7jxrTlaw&t=89s)

Comment: what's the Omit for ?

Comment: The Omit is there to omit the union type from the set of all strings so typescript won't collapse the string type( which is a larger set) and the union type to string.

Comment: @PraveenPuglia this solution works, but 
`x | omit<string, x> == string`. So you will get the autocomplete but not type safety. As user can still assign as='jsjsjsj' and it won't complain. If this is the required behavior then this solution is sufficient.

Comment: The ideal would be to have type safety as well but couldn't figure out anything that does both of these things.